# phoneGap view navigation from native to html page in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to PhoneGap. Can any one help me my Problem.

My Question

I have two html pages.

1)index.html,

2)login.html

3)NativeApp.h

4)NativeApp.m   files.

i am able to navigating from index.html to native code to using

Crodova.exec(null,null,Native,callMethod,[parms]);

now i am unable to move to native to login.html

can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per my understanding you want to do something on the native side and then move to login page.
In order to do that use CDVPluginResult which is part of phonegap framework in order to send your result back to the js .

Once you get the result in js (some kind of flag/json or anything you desire you can do the necessary work)

CDVPluginResult *pluginResult  = nil;
pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];

As a reference you can see many phonegap plugins already implemented on GitHub.

Comment: hi Ecko, i am very new to phoneGap. can Please explain clearly and if don't mine could please provide step like that it's very urgent.. please.

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/shazron/KeychainPlugin/blob/master/src/ios/CDVKeychain.m